Venting Dryer from the roof
I want to put a stackable washer-dryer in the middle of the house next to the existing bathroom.
I would like to vent the dryer on the side of the house. The main problem is accessing the side wall to vent the dryer.
Unfortunately the siding of the house is not accessible from the attic because the ceiling height is too high inside the house - as in this picture.

Will it pass the code for the dryer vent pipe to go through the attic and connect to the roof?
I read vertical vent for dryer is not a good idea - it might damage the roof etc.



I think you want the washer and dryer closest to the bedrooms, as that is where most of the wash comes from.  Although in our house, it's on opposite side near the kitchen because 1) that's where a lot a time is spent and 2) there was no space for a washer & dryer near the bedrooms.

You didn't say what kind of roof you have.  Do you have an attic?  Running the dryer vent pipe up into the attic, then out through the side of the house is pretty standard.

@Triplefault - I have re-written the question and changed it to ask a specific area and not ask for opinion. Kindly, please remove the request for closure as I made it on-topic.

+1 and voted to reopen

Nice edit! +1, Voting to reopen.

Good excuse to look at a ventless (heat pump) dryer.

Why don't you go out over the bedroom and exit through the side of the gabled end of the roof?  That would be standard wall exit arrangement and is the method I chose for my installation.

And the exit you showed in your picture through the top of the wall under the roof overhang is not allowed if you have a vented soffit, as it allows warm, moist air to be drawn into the attic.

There is no gable for this house. I've put the roof picture in the question.

@SteveSh - yes under the roof overhang is not a good idea as you said. I don't have gable also as the roof covers the top of the house as shown in the pic above.

Ahhh, I see now.  You have what I think is called a hip roof - no gables (as you said).  So looks you don't have much choice except to exit through the roof.  I am not aware of any code restrictions that forbid venting a dryer through the roof, others here may know.  I have a powder room vent that exhausts through the roof and have never had any issues with it.  Just have to ensure the flashing around the exhaust is done right,  They make exhaust vents just for this purpose.

Do you have a basement?  If so, you may be able to come down through the floor and over through a basement wall.

Thanks @SteveSh ! I would like to know the special roof vent for this type of situations in case we go that route. Do your remember it? Re: basement - yes we have basement and currently the floor is partially open since we are also re-doing the bathroom but the problem is the two joist-gaps where we want to put the dryer are a bit busy with basement's bathroom steam pipe; basement kitchen's range-hood pipe...etc but I'll dig in a bit more if we can squeeze in this pipe somewhere.

Run it through the floor joists and out the sidewall.
